# Scala Macro - error referencing class symbol "not found: value <class>"

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm trying to create a Scala macro that generates code like:

```
val x = new com.foo.MyClass()
```

where `com.foo.MyClass` is definitely on the classpath at compile time and run time in the project using the macro.

I'm using the following `c.Tree` to generate the code: 
`Apply(Select(New(Ident(TermName("com.foo.MyClass"))), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List())`

Printing the output of the `show` and `showRaw` commands indicate that the correct code is generated, however it seems that `com.foo.MyClass` either isn't on the class path during *macro expansion* or during compilation immediately after.

I'm seeing the following error generated at the usage point of the macro (the macro impl itself is defined in a separate project):

```
[ERROR] /src/main/java/foo/MyWhatever.scala:10: not found: value com.foo.MyClass
[ERROR]     MyMacros.someMacro(someInput)
[ERROR]
```

Why is it failing to find this class on the classpath even though it's a Java file in the same project? I tried `-Ymacro-debug-verbose` and `com.foo.MyClass` isn't in the output, but a bunch of other Java & Scala classes are. I can't find a pattern to which classes are on the classpath for the Macro expansion.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I managed to answer my own question. It turns out it works to use `c.mirror.staticClass("com.foo.MyClass")` to use compile-time reflection to get a class Symbol, then use Quasi-quotes.

My solution:

```
val classSymbol = c.mirror.staticClass("com.foo.MyClass")
val newClassTree = q"new ${classSymbol.toType}()"
c.Expr { newClassTree } // Success! This compiles and runs
```